# sum of costs from another table by current ID

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have 4 tables:

"Cars" table, where every car has an ID.

"Operations" table that holds the operations have been done on a car.

```
| ID  | CarID | Operation | User | JournalID |
| --- | ----- | --------- | ---- | --------- |
```

"Transactions" table that records the costs of the operations and other daily expenses, where every operation has 2 transactions, one is > 0 and the other is < 0 (for example: +100 and -100):

```
| ID  | Account | JournalID | Amount | Date |
| --- | ------- | --------- | ------ | ---- |
```

"Journal" table that records the daily finance:

```
| ID  | Amount | Date |
| --- | ------ | ---- |
```

What I want is knowing the sum of operations costs `amount` of a specific car, I was looping through all operations of that car and then looping for every journal row to sum, which lead to a bad result of course.

What can I do in that case to get the result as fast as possible?

NOTE: ALL THE NAMES OF THE COLUMNS ARE IN LOWER CASE

Comment: No, because journal is not only for car recordings.

Comment: What is the relevance of `Transactions` ?

Comment: It records everything that has been in and out the safe, car operations and other expenses (bills, salaries....)

Comment: I am using this Double Entry Accounting method: https://medium.com/@RobertKhou/double-entry-accounting-in-a-relational-database-2b7838a5d7f8

Answer (score 2):

You need to join three tables based on the foreign keys like this and with some select and raw query you can get solution to your problem.

```
DB::table('cars')->join('operations','cars.id','operations.car_id')
                 ->join('journal','journal.id','operations.journal_id')
                 ->select(DB::raw('SUM(amount) as total_cost'),'cars.*')
                 ->groupBy('cars.id')
                 ->get();
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I got, I appreciate your kind checking:
`SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'amount' in 'field list' (SQL: select SUM(amount) as total_cost, `cars`.* from `cars` inner join `operations` on `cars`.`id` = `operations`.`car_id` inner join `journal` on `journal`.`id` = `operations`.`journal_id` group by `cars`.`id`)`

Comment: @tinyCoder Is your column is Amount and not amount ? if so just replace the keyword

Comment: Actually the problem is that i miss-descibed my situation, I edited the question, i apologies it was my rushing mistake.

Comment: Actually of course because we are not including the `transactions` table in the query, so I edited your answer to join it and i got a result, but it is 0 total_cost, because the amount sum is always zero until i filter the result `where account = 0` in the joined transactions table, that is still not working anyway.

Comment: I want to add WHERE to the joined table `join('transactions','transactions.journal_id','operations.journal_id')` and that will fix it.

Comment: @tinyCoder I've got totally messed up, quite more confusing :D

Comment: I got it solved, I posted my answer, thanks for your help!

Comment: @tinyCoder any way congrats :)

Comment: Thank you @Sagar, your answer was really useful.

Comment: @tinyCoder ha ha it's okay have fun :D :D

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving it with @Segar's answer modified:

```
$result = DB::table('cars')
                 ->join('operations','cars.id','operations.car_id')
                 ->join('journal','journal.id','operations.journal')
                 ->join('transactions','transactions.journal','operations.journal')->where('transactions.type', 0)
                 ->select(DB::raw('SUM(amount) as total_cost'),'cars.*')
                 ->groupBy('cars.id')
                 ->get();

print_r($result);
```

Thanks.